# mgcv optimization: why optimize **log** smooth parameter?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, optimization, generalized-additive-model, smoothing, mgcv

In mgcv package, when optimizing smoothing parameters (in the outer iteration), one take the partial derivative of objective function with respect to $\rho = log(\lambda)$. My question is why not take the partial derivative with respective to $\lambda$?

The detailed algorithm is in this paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.03864.pdf

Comment: Perhaps you can provide very specific references (page, equation number, or whatever) as to exactly what you're talking about, both in the linked paper and the mgcv documentation?

Comment: If you work on the log scale, you don't have a bound at 0 to deal with.

Comment: @Mark L. Stone. It's on page 5 on the linked reference, **Outer algorithm for $\rho$**, we take the partial derivative of V with respect to $\rho$. My question is why not taking partial derivative of V with respect to $\lambda$ ? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @jbowman. If we work on the log scale, do we get the same optimal $\lambda$ as we work on the original scale?

Comment: Looking at the paper, it seems clear to me that you would, subject of course to the fact that you're taking a different path to the optimal solution and therefore will likely wind up at a slightly different place.  The $\log$ being a monotonic transform is helpful here!